# ValueError: shapes (4,4) and (3,4) not aligned: 4 (dim 1) != 3 (dim 0)

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have two matrices;

```
A = 
 [[ 2  2  1  3]
 [ 3  0 -2  3]
 [ 3 -3  1  2]] 

C = 
 [[ 4  0  2  2]
 [ 1 -2  0  1]
 [ 2  1  5 -3]
 [ 5  2  1  4]]
```

Im currently trying to multiply them;

```
print(C.dot(A))
```

however, I'm getting the below error.

```
ValueError: shapes (4,4) and (3,4) not aligned: 4 (dim 1) != 3 (dim 0)
```

I can do the following;

```
print(A.dot(C))
[[27  3 12 15]
 [23  4 -1 24]
 [21 11 13  8]]
```

but is this the same as CA?

Thank you.

Comment: With `dot` the basic rule is that the last of dimension of `A` pairs with the 2nd-to-the-last of `B`.  This is the same as the manual across columns, down rows method of matrix multiplication.  The one that works is a (3,4) with a (4,4) resulting in a (3,4).

Comment: No, `A.dot(C)` is not the same as `C.dot(A)` even when the [multiplication makes sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Non-commutativity).

Comment: Yes, the middle two must be equal. Rotating your array _might_ help. See https://cdn.kastatic.org/googleusercontent/qCWpcd2cPFXad5omuF_ulaYlaBomeBw5RS_9GYLUJg9lZd25SIuvConuu_CfoGBzZJjZGr05602QTJyR0JImBeG39A where (mxn).(nxk), meaning that the two middle dimensions must be equal.